Oracle Java 8 update 411だけWindowsのコマンドライン引数の文字コードの扱いが異なる
以下のようなプログラムを書きました。
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("please specify at least an argument.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("Hello world!: args[0] = " + args[0]);
    }
}

これをWindowsのコマンドプロンプト（またはPowerShell）で以下のように引数を与えて実行します。
java -jar argtest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar テスト

この結果が、Java Runtimeによって異なってしまうのです。
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7, mixed mode)

だと、
Hello world!: args[0] = テスト

となるのですが、
java version "1.8.0_411"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_411-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.411-b09, mixed mode)

だと、
Hello world!: args[0] = 繝・せ繝

と文字化けしてしまいます。
手元に環境がないのですが、Oracle Java 8 u401では正常だったという報告を受けています。
こちら、コマンドライン引数の文字コードを明に指定するのが正しく、ほかの環境ではたまたま動いていたということはあるのでしょうか？ その場合、方法をご教示いただけると助かります。
それともu411における仕様変更だったりするのでしょうか？ （リリースノートを確認したところでは該当する記述は発見できませんでした。）

2024.05.18 追記
Windowsのバージョンは Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.4291
主にコマンドプロンプトで実行していますが、念のためPowerShellのバージョンは 5.1.19041.4291
ビルドJDKはOracle Java 1.8.0_411-b09でした
System.getProperty("file.encoding") が返す値はいずれも MS932 です。

WindowsおよびPowerShellのバージョンと、Javaコードのコンパイルに使用しているJDKのバージョンを記載してください。また、JavaコードでSystem.getProperty("file.encoding")が返す値をそれぞれのJREで出力してみてください。

まずコマンドプロンプトでchcp 65001を実行した後、java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <JARファイル名> [任意のコマンドラインオプション]を実行してみてください。

ちなみにJARファイルは後方互換性 (backward compatibility) はあるものの、前方互換性 (forward compatibility) は保証されません。古いJDKでビルドしたJARを新しいJREで実行することはできますが、新しいJDKでビルドしたJARを古いJREで実行してはいけません。詳しくはJAR File Specification | Java SE 11などを参照してください。


コマンドプロンプトでchcp 65001を実行した後、java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <JARファイル名> [任意のコマンドラインオプション]を実行

結果変わらずですね……。

ちなみにビルドJDKについての回答が間違っていてJDK11でビルドしたものをJRE11で実行してました（結果正常なのに、何を勘違いしていたのだ）。

JavaコードでSystem.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")が返す値を出力してみてください。また、コマンドプロンプトでchcp 65001を実行した後、java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <JARファイル名> [任意のコマンドラインオプション]を実行した場合はどうなりますか？

「JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS」「_JAVA_OPTIONS」「JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS」などの環境変数を設定していませんか？その他、JAVAとつく環境変数があれば全て上げてください。

System.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding") は、CP932のときは ms932、CP65001のときは cp65001 でした。またコマンドライン引数で -Dsun.stdout.encoding を指定しても結果変わらずでした。

環境変数の設定は特にしていません。実際に set | find ”JAVA" しても何も出ませんでした。

UTF-8のバイト列を無理やりCP932（Shift_JIS）と解釈しているような化け方をしていますが、もしchcpとfile.encodingとsun.stdout.encodingをすべてUTF-8に設定しても効かないということであれば、Javaのバグであるような気がします。Java 18ではデフォルトのテキストエンコーディングがUTF-8に変更されましたが、それ以前のバージョンでは本来システムロケールに準拠する仕様だったはず。問題の切り分けのため、コマンドラインオプション自体は正しく渡っているかどうか、String中のUTF-16文字コードを整数値で出力してみてください。素直にループを回してintとして出力してもいいし、args[0].chars().forEach(System.out::println);のようにIntStreamを使ってもいいです。もし"テスト"が正しく渡ってJavaのStringとなっているのであれば、12486, 12473, 12488の3つが出力されるはず。

args[0].chars().forEach(System.out::println); した結果は 32349 ,12539, 12379, 32349 でした。cp932でもcp65001でも同じです。
JRE11だと、12486, 12473, 12488 になります。

コマンドラインオプションの文字列を渡した段階ですでに化けているということですね。Red Hatが配布しているOpenJDK 8 / JRE 8のWindows用最新バイナリ jdk-8u412-x64 / jre-8u412-x64を使った場合はどうなりますか？　もしOpenJDK 8 / JRE 8でも再現する場合、ソースコードの差分を調べてみれば何か分かるかもしれません。

OpenJDK 8u412では再現しませんでした。

そんなわけでOracle JREの不具合である旨報告しようと思うのですが、どこから報告すればよいかわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/bugreports002.html ここからたどれるリンクの https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/index.jsp ここを経由して https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/ ここでバグ報告しようとするとAccess Deniedになってしまいます。
